# Перевод текста даты в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, дата

Есть установленный Wordpress (Eng)

**function.php**

```
function my_post_time_ago_function() {
    return sprintf( esc_html__( '%s ago', 'textdomain' ), human_time_diff(get_the_time ( 'U' ), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) );
}
add_filter( 'the_time', 'my_post_time_ago_function' );
```

**Вывод даты**

```
<? the_time(); ?>
```

Далее в постах отображается, пример: **16 hours ago**, **4 days ago** .

Вопрос, как заменить, слова **hours**, **days** на нужный мне язык ?

Мне не нужно "переводить весь wordpress", а только два эти слова.

Comment: Это зависит от того, какая локализация у Вас выбрана в настройках сайта и в зависимости от этой локализации будет использоваться соответствующий файл перевода. Потому весьма логично, что если сайт eng, то и язык будет использоваться английский.

Comment: Потому если Вам уж очень надо перевести только hours и days и нужно чтобы по каким-то причинам только это было на каком-то другом языке, а весь сайт так и оставался на английском, то Вам нужно будет написать собственный аналог функции `human_time_diff()`, либо обработать ее вывод, с заменой соответствующих слов, а их там будет больше чем просто hours и days.

Comment: English (United States) - а где можно изменить или заменить ? Так как нет каталога wp-content/languages/

Comment: Settings -> General -> Site Language

Comment: Я имел ввиду не весь язык, а именно строку, ведь где-то текст days, hours хранится ?

Comment: Вы же понимаете что функция `human_time_diff()` используется не только там где Вы ее написали? Перевод в `wp-content/languages/` может быть перезаписан с обновлением WordPress или языкового пакета.

Comment: sprintf( esc_html__( '%s ago', 'textdomain' ) - запихнуть в переменную потом str replace ?

Comment: Можете повесить фильтр на [human_time_diff](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/human_time_diff/), и там уже делать `str_replace()` или другие манипуляции в рамках нужной Вам логики.

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/codex/date-time-api/date-formats - Локализация. Но сперва https://developer.wordpress.org/coding-standards/wordpress-coding-standards/php/#no-shorthand-php-tags

Comment: str_replace("days,"any text", human_time_diff())